# How can select multiple values of an array of random numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, random, dice

I am creating a dice program to further my learning. The program will roll 5 dice and assign random number values to an array of 5 and print out the values. After that I am wanting the player to select the die or dice that he or she would like to keep, display those values and later I will create a method to roll the remaining dice.

I am having a problem with the selecting multiple dice part.

This is what I have so far:

```
    using System;


class HelloWorld {

  static void Main() {

    Random random = new Random();

    int[] diceEach = new int[5];


    int diceCount = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        diceEach[i] = random.Next(1, 7);
        Console.WriteLine("Dice " + diceCount +": " + diceEach[i]);
        diceCount++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("To roll again hit R");

    Console.WriteLine("Please type the dice numbers that you would like to keep...");
    string diceKept = Console.ReadLine();

        if(diceKept == "1")
        {
            Console.Write(diceEach[0]);
        }

        else if(diceKept == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(diceEach[1]);
        }

        else if(diceKept == "3")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(diceEach[2]);
        }

        else if(diceKept == "4")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(diceEach[3]);
        }

        else if(diceKept == "5")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(diceEach[4]);
        }

        else if(diceKept == "r")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen to roll again");
        }


    Console.ReadLine();

  }

}
```

I have it currently printing out one dice value that you select but I wasn't sure how to print out multiple selections. The only way I can think of is typing out all the options. But that doesn't seem right and would make my code so long.

I was thinking some sort of a loop might work? But I can see how.

This is my first time posting here so hopefully I did it right. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably want to look into `Int.TryParse(…)` to avoid "1,1,3,4,5" error in current post... and search for "how to print list in C#"... and search for "how to ask user for input multiple times in C# console app" … and think whether your dice are actulually fair (the same) or weighted (unfair) to see if you need to remember just results + count or exact positions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way you could solve it would be to loop until the user is done selecting dice to keep and wants to re-roll using a **do...while** loop.

```
        string diceKept;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please type the dice number that you would like to keep...and type 'r' to when finished to re-roll remaining dice");
            diceKept = Console.ReadLine();

            if(int.TryParse(diceKept, out var diceNumber))
            {
                // I am making an assumption here that the user will always input a number between 1-6.
                // It would be best to put some logic to catch that scenario though.
                Console.WriteLine(diceEach[diceNumber - 1]);
            }

        } while (diceKept.ToLower() != "r");

        Console.WriteLine("Now re-rolling the rest....");
        // Do some re-relling stuff here.
        Console.Read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get multiple user selections by letting him input his chosen dices separating them by comma ',' for example

```
1,2,5
```

then expand the code

```
string diceKept = Console.ReadLine();

try{
    int[] selectedDices = diceKept.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
}catch{
//invalid input - string value could not be parsed to int value.
}
```

you can use try-catch block in a function, then if erros has not been throwed continue your work, else retry input of selected values.